# How to give a directory back its sudo admissions/permissions?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I recently installed LAMP on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. But I didn't have full/root access to the files `var/www` and `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` so I did some research to change permissions and admissions to the directory, using this command in the terminal:

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

It worked perfectly. But now I can't do any sudo commands in the terminal. I wanted to restart the apache server but here is what it showed me:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: impossible d'initialiser le greffon de règles
```

(my computer is in french btw).
What I want to know is how to set it back to sudo. I hope I explained myself good enough. If you need additional info that I didn't state please tell me. I will add it. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you `chown`'d `/etc/sudoers`.

Try:

`sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers`

Then if you want read/write privileges, see which group the folder `/var/www` belongs to (probably `www-data`)

To add yourself to the `www-data` group, try:

`sudo useradd -a -G www-data yourUserName`

Also, as a side note; be careful of recursive commands!!! If you're not sure what a command does, test it on a single file before making it recursive. For example:

**DO NOT RUN THIS CODE, I DON'T INCLUDE SUDO ON PURPOSE SO YOU DONT HOSE EVERYTHING**

`rm -r /`

Will delete everything inside `/` (a lot of stuff!)

Comment: Still doesnt work it gives me the error message- `chown: modification du propriétaire de «/etc/sudoers»: Opération non permise`. Meaning the modification of the file owner of `/etc/sudoers`: Operation is not allowed.

Comment: @Calvin, Can you run the command without `sudo`? I kinda forgot we couldn't escalate ourselves.